# How to make a CRUD correctly in QUASAR Framework using Laravel for the API?

Tags: vue.js, laravel-8, store, quasar-framework, quasar

I am currently working with Quasar 2.5.4 but there is not much information on how to make a CRUD using **store** which already includes "actions,getter,index,mutations,state".

Any example please :(